# Form-fill XFA PDF with PDFBox

Tags: forms, pdfbox, xfa

I'm trying to fill an XFA form using the example file using PdfBox 2 or 3 from:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12964530/XFAFormFiller.java

I'm not so used to PDFBox so not sure how to correct it.

1. I get compile errors. Basically how can I make it compile with latest PDFBox? Are my corrections below correct?

```
Line 107 I tried to fix with
Set<COSDictionary> objectsToWrite = new HashSet<>();

Line 121 I tried to fix with
COSWriter writer = new COSWriter(fos, new RandomAccessReadBuffer(baos.toByteArray()), objectsToWrite);

Line 128 I tried to fix with:
objectsToWrite.add(dataSetsStream);
```

2. What format should the XML input file be? Can someone give an example?
   I get a corrupt PDF out with my corrections and feeding it the XML generated from dataSetsStream.
   The file I feed:

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"
><xfa:data
><mycompany
>
.....
><mycompany
></dd:dataDescription
></xfa:datasets
>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My code fixes actually worked. The reason I could not get it to work was that I read in the XML-file (which was in ISO-8859-1 encoded) as UTF-8 encoding and then the viewer got confused and complained about bad xml tag.
So my fix (for my case) was to change Line 92 to following instead:

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(xmlData, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

Comment: But if someone PDFBox expert could verify my fixes are correct so I can help PDFBox document it.

Comment: The `XFAFormFiller` class you found was an attachment to some issue in the Apache Jira, so it is not an example file and not part of the PDFBox code base; this is also illustrated by the package `com.airvoyant.pdf` of the class. Strictly speaking neither the original `"UTF-8"` nor your `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` is correct for generic use. The correct fix would be to not use a `InputStreamReader` at all: what the code reads from the `InputStreamReader`, it writes to an `Outputstream`, so the decoding by the `InputStreamReader` is incorrect in any way.